# Merge two dataframes by randomly shuffling the indices

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, shuffle

There are two dataframes called df1 and d2 each looking exactly the same and having indices 1 to n (in the example 1-2)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'],
    'Indices': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'Value': [10, 20, 30, 40]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'],
    'Indices': [1, 1, 2, 2],
    'Value': [50, 60, 70, 80]
})
```

I have a third dataframe which has exactly double the size, having indices from 1 to 2*n.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'],
    'Indices': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'Value': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

I would like to fill df3 in a way that for each "fruit" it fills the values in a random shuffled order from all elements of both df1 and df2.

So for "Apple", one would have 10, 30, 50 and 70 available, for "Pineapple", it would be 20,40,60,80, but both shuffled.

The result could then look like this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'],
    'Indices': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'Value': [10, 80, 30, 60, 70, 40, 50, 20]
})
```

but of course also like this (or anything else random which meets the Fruit sorted condition)

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'],
    'Indices': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
    'Value': [30, 60, 70, 80, 10, 40, 50, 20]
})
```

is there a clever way to do this?

I know that I can select the correct data by loc and that there is a sampling method in pandas, but how does that all combine?

Comment: (Fruit, Indices) is always unique in `df3`? Does indices matter to fill values?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that information. (Fruit, Indices) is always unique and complete without the range.

Comment: The indices don’t matter at all, since I want the new one shuffled, but still grouped by fruit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge`. With this method all values from `df1` and `df2` will be allocated without duplicates:

```
# Create a temporary dataframe with an idx column
df4 = (pd.concat([df1, df2]).sample(frac=1, ignore_index=True)
         .assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby('Fruit').cumcount()))

# Merge df3 and df4 on (Fruit, idx)
df3['Value'] = (df3.assign(idx=lambda x: x.groupby('Fruit').cumcount())
                   .merge(df4, on=['Fruit', 'idx'])['Value_y'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
       Fruit  Indices  Value
0      Apple        1     30
1  Pineapple        1     80
2      Apple        2     70
3  Pineapple        2     60
4      Apple        3     10
5  Pineapple        3     40
6      Apple        4     50
7  Pineapple        4     20
```

**Another way**

(but the two methods below don't guarantee value is unique)

```
>>> (df3.merge(pd.concat([df1, df2]), on='Fruit', suffixes=(None, '_'))
        .groupby(['Fruit', 'Indices'], sort=False).sample(n=1)[df3.columns])

        Fruit  Indices  Value
0       Apple        1     70
4       Apple        2     10
11      Apple        3     50
12      Apple        4     50
18  Pineapple        1     20
21  Pineapple        2     60
27  Pineapple        3     80
31  Pineapple        4     40
```

Or if you want to preserve order:

```
>>> (df3.reset_index().merge(pd.concat([df1, df2]), on='Fruit', suffixes=(None, '_'))
        .groupby('index').sample(n=1).set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None)[df3.columns])

       Fruit  Indices  Value
0      Apple        1     30
1  Pineapple        1     80
2      Apple        2     70
3  Pineapple        2     60
4      Apple        3     10
5  Pineapple        3     40
6      Apple        4     50
7  Pineapple        4     20
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you exactly are looking for, but maybe this helps:

```
for fruit in df3.Fruit.unique():
    df3.loc[df3['Fruit'] == fruit, 'Value'] = pd.concat([df1, df2])[pd.concat([df1, df2]).Fruit == fruit].sample(frac=1).Value.to_list()
df3.Value = df3.Value.astype(int)
print(df3)
```

Result:

```
       Fruit  Indices  Value
0      Apple        1     30
1  Pineapple        1     60
2      Apple        2     70
3  Pineapple        2     20
4      Apple        3     50
5  Pineapple        3     40
6      Apple        4     10
7  Pineapple        4     80
```

Answer (score 0):

By using *fruits* mapping made from combining `df1` and `df2` column values:

```
fruits_map = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop('Indices', axis=1)\
    .groupby('Fruit')['Value'].agg(list).to_dict()
df3['Value'] = [np.random.choice(fruits_map[f]) for f in df3['Fruit']]
```

---

Sample `df3`:

```
       Fruit  Indices  Value
0      Apple        1     10
1  Pineapple        1     60
2      Apple        2     70
3  Pineapple        2     60
4      Apple        3     70
5  Pineapple        3     60
6      Apple        4     30
7  Pineapple        4     60
```

Comment: Does fruits.choice take into account all values in the end, or just 2*n choices which may contain duplicates?

Comment: @Hemmelig, `random.choice` get a random sample from a sequence. Was your intention to shuffle all values for a fruit on each sample without possible duplication with previous samples?

Comment: Yes :) sorry, maybe the entire question is written badly

Comment: @Hemmelig, do you want to repeat shuffling for each duplicated fruit OR shuffle just once all values for each unique fruit?

Comment: Individual shuffle for each fruit